# Google API PHP Client library release date

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm using this library for a big CRM system. The latest version 1.0.* is not stable enough to use in production, especially as Drive client. Do you have a deadline for a stable version or a road map for developement process?

Comment: I don't think there's a roadmap, but you could ask one of the maintainers directly, not sure if they answer things here (check the github contributors page)

Comment: may be you're right. thnx for advice